# display in decimal the total of 2 numbers

Tags: javascript, html

im trying to display the 2 decimal point of the 2 total number and minus them but it didnt compute the decimal point. anyone would like to figure this out. thanks.

```
function calculate() {

    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
    var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
    var basicpay = document.getElementById('basicpay');
    var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
    basicpay.value = myResult.toFixed(2);

    document.getElementById('both').value = sum() - diff();
}
```

this is the diff part

```
function diff() {

    var absent = document.getElementById('absent').value;
    var tardiness = document.getElementById('tardiness').value;
    var sss = document.getElementById('sss').value;
    var pagibig = document.getElementById('pagibig').value;
    var philhealth = document.getElementById('philhealth').value;
    var cashadvances = document.getElementById('cashadvances').value;
    var withholdingtax = document.getElementById('withholdingtax').value;
    var others = document.getElementById('others').value;

    var result =

        parseInt(absent) +
        parseInt(tardiness) +
        parseInt(sss) +
        parseInt(pagibig) +
        parseInt(philhealth) +
        parseInt(cashadvances) +
        parseInt(withholdingtax) +
        parseInt(others) || 0;


    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        document.getElementById('totaldeductions').value = result.toFixed(2);
        return result;
    }
}
```

this is the sum part

```
function sum() {
    var basicpay = document.getElementById('basicpay').value;
    var overtime = document.getElementById('overtime').value;
    var regularholiday = document.getElementById('regularholiday').value;
    var specialholiday = document.getElementById('specialholiday').value;
    var allowanceday = document.getElementById('allowanceday').value;
    var monthpay = document.getElementById('monthpay').value;
    var others1 = document.getElementById('others1').value;

    var result =

        parseInt(basicpay) +
        parseInt(overtime) +
        parseInt(regularholiday) +
        parseInt(specialholiday) +
        parseInt(allowanceday) +
        parseInt(monthpay) +
        parseInt(others1) || 0;

    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        document.getElementById('totalgrosspay').value = result.toFixed(2);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: add your markup as well. What is `sum() & diff()`.

Comment: What are `sum()` and `diff()`? What wrong value is displayed?

Comment: "im trying to display the 2 decimal point of the 2 total number and minus them but it didnt compute the decimal point" sounds like you need to first spend some time to make sure your code computes the decimal point, then? When that doesn't work and you have code that you believe should, time to ask here?

Answer (score 1):

In your Sum() and Diff() function, you are working only with integers. Integers are whole numbers only, so will not retain anything after a decimal point. To deal with decimals, you will need to use JavaScript's parseFloat() function. To give an example, in your Sum() function you would change the result calculation to look like the following:

```
var result = 

    parseFloat(basicpay) + 
    parseFloat(overtime) +
    parseFloat(regularholiday) +
    parseFloat(specialholiday) +
    parseFloat(allowanceday) +
    parseFloat(monthpay) +
    parseFloat(others1) || 0;
```

This will retain the decimal points in the numbers rather than truncating to whole numbers as the parseInt()